# conditions for idempotence in $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\\\end{bmatrix}$.  I'm looking for the conditions such that $A^2=A$.  So I start calculating...
$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} a^2+bc&ab+bd\\ac+cd&bc+d^2\\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\\\end{bmatrix}=A$$
So there are things we can find...we have

1)  $ab+bd=b\rightarrow b(a+d)=b \rightarrow (a+d)=1 \rightarrow d=(1-a).$  This tells me that $Tr(A^2)=Tr(A)=1$ under this condition of idempotence.  Calculation on $ac+cd=c$ produces the same result, that $d=(1-a)$

2)  $a^2+bc=a \rightarrow bc=a-a^2 \rightarrow bc=a(1-a)\rightarrow bc=ad\rightarrow ad-bc=0 \rightarrow det(A)=0$.  This leads me to that idempotent matrix is singular.  Calculation

So it would seem that these were shown to be true by direct calculation.  Yet the Identity matrix $I_2$ is clearly idempotent and yet $Tr(I_2)=2$ and $det(I_2)=1$  So why is this the case?  How does the direct calculation not support the identity case?  Are there any easier ways to show the above while including the case of $I_2$?

Comment: $b(a+d) = b$ implies $b=0$ or $a+d=1$.

Comment: Oh yeah....should have seen that.  So then my above analysis holds for all cases where $b\neq 0$, the identity?

Comment: Have you done anything with eigenvalues/eigenvectors? Bringing those in would make solving this problem in the $2\times 2$ case, and in general, much easier.

Comment: I mean, i know that $\lambda^2 - Tr(A)\lambda +det(A)$ is the characteristic polynomial, and that, outside the $b=0$ case, the eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $A^2=A$ the eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ or $1$. We have three cases:

**Case 1**: $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$. Then the characteristic Polynomial of $A$ is $X^2=0$. Then $A^2=0$ and hence $A=A^2=0$.

**Case 2**: $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$. Then $A$ is invertible, and we get $A^2=A \Rightarrow A=I$.

**Case 3**: $\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2=1$. Then $A$ is diagonalizable and hence

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} x&y\\z&t\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x&y\\z&t\\\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{xt-zt} \begin{bmatrix} x&y\\z&t\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} t&-y\\-z&x\\\end{bmatrix}=... $$

Comment: This answer could use a justification for the assumption that there are two eigenvalues.

Comment: @user2357112 What do you mean? Any $n \times n$ matrix has exactly $n$ eigenvalues (counting multiplicity). And the given matrix is $2 \times 2$....

Comment: @user2357112 Note that by multiplicity I don't mean the geometric multiplicity. The eigenvalues of a matrix are the roots, including multiplicity, of its characteristic equation....

Comment: Oh, algebraic multiplicity. I always think of geometric multiplicity by default.

Answer (score 5):

By Cayley-Hamilton we know that $A^2-Tr(A)A+\det(A)I_2=0$. Hence $A^2=A$ means $A=I_2$, $A=0$, or $\det(A)=0$ and $Tr(A)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an $N\times N$ matrix such that $A^{2}=A$, then $A$ is a projection matrix. Every $y\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$ can be written as
$$
      y= Ay +(I-A)y .
$$
Notice that $A(Ay)=(Ay)$ and $A(I-A)y=0$. That is, $A$ is $I$ on the range of $A$ and is $0$ on the range of $I-A$. So there is a basis $\{ y_{1},\ldots,y_{N}\}$ such that the transformed matrix $A$ is 0 everywhere except on the diagonal, where it will have 1's or 0's. The case for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a special case.